# I am getting a Error as Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-views

I am having a Asp.Net MVC application I am getting below error every time, especially when there is a list or a table. I tried to fix it but unable to figure out a solution. Can anyone help me please? 
Script Error as in Google Chrome DevTool is as below:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312
>   n @ vendor-all.min.js:4

I checked the js file but could not find a fix.

[image]

Comment: When you're attaching that specific listener, mark the passive property to `false`: `.addEventListener('touchmove', handler, {passive: false});`. I've used `touchmove` event in the example, but you use the event you need, of course. More infromation in [parameters chapter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: It looks like Chrome has now made passing the passive property to the specific events mandatory, if the event wants to prevent the default action. There probably will be a ton of posted questions about this in the near future.